# Puppet master certificate generation not working

Tags: puppet

***Puppet Master:***

- Docker container with cent-OS-6
- configured in /etc/hosts
- configured /etc/puppet/puppet.conf with **server**,**dns_alt_names** and
  **certname**

**Puppet Agent:**

- Docker container  with ubuntu OS
- configured serverip and agent ip in /etc/hosts
- configure /etc/puppet/puppet.conf with **server** value

**NOW trying to Generate Certificate in SERVER Machine with**

```
sudo -u puppet puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose
```

Displays:*`Notice: Starting Puppet master version 3.8.7`*

*Nothing happens  related to Certificate Generation.*

I believe there aint any mistake in hosts file and other configuration missing. here might have things gone wrong.

**In the client machine**
If I run this command **puppet agent -t** . I get the following error. As the certificate is not generated in server. I think I have to fix that first than this .

```
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://www.puppetmaster.com/pluginfacts: Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://www.puppetmaster.com/plugins: Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: Server hostname 'www.puppetmaster.com' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetcertificate, DNS:puppet www.puppetmaster.com, DNS:puppetcertificate
```

Comment: don't install 3.8.7, don't use centos 6 ...

Answer (score 2):

First, try setting [dns_alt_names](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/configuration.html#dnsaltnames) in /etc/puppet/puppet.conf:

```
[main]
    dns_alt_names = www.puppetmaster.com
[master]
    autosign = true
```

Then see if your puppet-agent -t run works properly. be sure that you have properly set your server on the puppet client in /etc/puppet/puppet.conf too:

```
[agent]
    server = www.puppetmaster.com
```